# How to change Sub-Folder field value programmatically - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have this folder structure in document library :

```
ROOT FOLDER 1
   ----> Sub Folder 1
   ----> Sub Folder 2
   ----> Document File

ROOT FOLDER 2
   ----> Sub Folder 1
   ----> Sub Folder 2
   ----> Document File
```

When I change the field value at some of columns of the Root Folder I want these changes to be applied on the subfolders and also to the document file too.

This is the code I wrote and I'm not sure what Im missing.

```
SPFolder folder = properties.List.RootFolder.SubFolders[properties.ListTitle + "/" +      properties.ListItem.Name];
SPFolderCollection rootColl = folder.SubFolders;

 MetadataDefaults columnDefaults = new MetadataDefaults(properties.List);

columnDefaults.RemoveAllDefaults();

if (rootColl != null)


   foreach (SPFolder selSubFolder in rootColl)
      {
         if (web.GetFolder(selSubFolder.ToString()).Exists)
              {
                columnDefaults.SetFieldDefault(selSubFolder, "Reviewers", string.Format(properties.ListItem["Reviewers"].ToString()));
                columnDefaults.Update();
                selSubFolder.Update();
                 selSubFolder.Item["Reviewers"] = properties.ListItem["Reviewers"];
                 properties.ListItem.Update();
                  properties.List.Update();

              }            
        }
   }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting ?

Comment: no issue, that is the biggest problem ,no exception,everything pass,the updates, but the changes are still not saved :S, only the root folder accept the changes...
Am I missing something ?

Comment: The file SOPDocuments/SOP-GEN01 has been modified by i:0#.w|domain\\user1 on "some date time"
This was the exception I catch when I was checking the changes at the subfolders...User1 is the user that is making the changes with edit properties...